# ZendX jQuery Autocomplete not working in framework

Tags: jquery, zend-framework, autocomplete, zendx

- I added the ZendX library.
- Added the helper in controller:

> ```
> public function init()
> {
>     $this->view->addHelperPath(
>         'ZendX/JQuery/View/Helper'
>         ,'ZendX_JQuery_View_Helper');
> }
> ```

- Created a form for view page:

> ```
> public function indexAction()
> {
>     // Filter form 
>     $this->view->autocompleteElement = new ZendX_JQuery_Form_Element_AutoComplete('txtLocation');
>     $this->view->autocompleteElement->setAttrib('placeholder', 'Search Location');
>     $this->view->autocompleteElement->setJQueryParam('data', array('Manila', 'Pasay', 'Mandaluyong', 'Pasig', 'Marikina','Makati'));
> }
> ```

- Load jQuery and form in view page.

> ```
> <?php echo $this->jQuery(); ?> 
> <form>
>     <?php echo $this->autocompleteElement; ?>
> </form>
> ```

The form is visible in the view page. But the autocomplete isn't working. I even don't see any jQuery script in the source page. Have I missed something?

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution here: http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=69&t=1889

Adding **echo $this->jQuery();** at the end of my view file instead of on the top solves the problem. I don't know what's the difference. Maybe an issue with Zend's layout generator.